# HID transfer comparison on different endpoints

Tags: usb, hid, adc

I'm using the SiLabs C8051F320 configured as a HID to stream ADC data (in 64B or 32B reports) to the PC. I'm basing my HID on the SiLabs example code, with bInterval = 1 and experimenting with endpoint 1 (EP1) versus endpoint 2 (EP2).

Per the C8051F320's datasheet, when the endpoints are in split mode, EP1 is 64B and EP2 is 128B when not double-buffered. I have EP1 as 64B when not double-buffered and 32B when double-buffered. EP2 is 64B whether or not double-buffered. The ADC data is 2 bytes per sample, so 31 samples in a 64B report and 15 samples in 32B report are transferred per report.

1) non-double-buffered EP1 (64B per report) streams 22.5kSps ADC data properly
2) double-buffered EP1 (32B per report) streams 11.5kSps ADC data properly
3) non-double-buffered EP2 (64B per report) does not stream 22.5kSps ADC data properly (I didn't check what's the max sample rate)
4) double-buffered EP2 (64B per report) samples 22.5kSps ADC data properly
5) It seems that the time to fill a report with samples must be longer than bInterval. For example, if bInterval were 10 instead of 1, then non-double-buffered EP1 streams 3kSps properly.

Does the above scenario look right? Why does EP1 allow faster transfer than EP2? Why does the report fill time need to be longer than bInterval?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the time to fill a report with samples must be longer than bInterval.

Correct: HID uses Interrupt type endpoints, they can transport one report every bInterval ms. That allows you to calculate maximum data rate at 64 Byte * 1000 Hz = 64000 Bytes in a sec.
With 2 Bytes in a sample this results in 32kHz maximum sampling rate.

> Why does EP1 allow faster transfer than EP2?

I can see no reason for this behavior besides a programming error.

Note: HID Protocol is a poor choice for streaming data. Bulk type endpoints allow much higher data throughput.